# Formatting several labels in BarChart

Tags: labeling, charts

I have the following BarChart with labels on the bars and labels at the bottom:

```
data = {0.55`, 0.19`, 0.21`, 0.94`, 0.79`, 0.07`, 0.82`, 0.12`, 0.15`,
    1.`, 0.15`, 0.12`, 0.76`, 0.8`, 0.069`, 0.71`};
labelsBar = {0.305`, -0.151`, 0.162`, 
   0.62`, -0.363`, -0.054`, -0.323`, 0.12`, 0.024`, -0.509`, -0.027`, 
   0.016`, 0.403`, 0.314`, -0.005`, -0.221`};
labelsBottom = {"ABC1", "ABC2", "ABC3", "ABC4", "ABC5", "ABC6", 
   "ABC7", "ABC8", "ABC9", "ABC10", "ABC11", "ABC12", "ABC13", 
   "ABC14", "ABC15", "ABC16"};
BarChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{labelsBar, labelsBottom}, {Top, Axis}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black}, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Table[If[labelsBar[[x]] < 0, Red, Blue], {x, 1, Length@labelsBar}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

I'm trying to format the labels differently, i.e. the labels on the bottom need to be rotated 90 degrees and should have a different style than the labels on the bars. Moreover, I want the labels on the bars be above them.

I tried using `Directive` to also rotate the bottom labels, but that gives me an error:

```
BarChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> 
  Placed[{labelsBar, labelsBottom}, {Top, 
    Directive[Axis, Rotate[#, Pi/2] &]}], LabelStyle -> {Black}, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Table[If[labelsBar[[x]] < 0, Red, Blue], {x, 1, Length@labelsBar}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

Also coloring the labels differently with `Labelstyle` seems not to be the correct approach, since now both labels are green and none is black:

```
BarChart[data, 
 ChartLabels -> Placed[{labelsBar, labelsBottom}, {Top, Axis}], 
 LabelStyle -> {Black, Green}, 
 ChartStyle -> 
  Table[If[labelsBar[[x]] < 0, Red, Blue], {x, 1, Length@labelsBar}], 
 ImageSize -> 600]
```

I must be missing something and hope for some help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think you get multiple labels per bar using `ChartLabels` only. In cases where you need more flexibility for styling and labeling of plot elements, you can often use wrappers around the data to specify what you need.

Below, I use two `Labeled` wrappers and one `Style` wrapper to specify the necessary information. The labels themselves are themselves wrapped in `Style`/`Rotate` to achieve the look you're after.

```
BarChart[
 MapThread[
  Labeled[
    Labeled[
     Style[#, If[#2 < 0, Red, Blue]],
     Style[#2, Green],
     Top],
    Rotate[Style[#3, Black], 90°],
    Axis
    ] &,
  {data, labelsBar, labelsBottom}
  ],
 ImageSize -> 600
 ]
```

[image]

Note that you could also add one set of labels using `ChartLabels`, and specify the bar colors using `ChartStyle` (as you did in the question). I just wanted to show how it can be done using just wrappers, to give you a better idea.

Comment: Thanks Lukas! Not sure if this is an easy or complicated solution, but would not have figured that out by myself :).